Make .Net Chart Major Grid lines align with x-axis annotations
I have a .Net chart with the X-Axis representing time. I would like to be able to set the X-axis Major Grid interval to values other than the default. If I use the default interval as shown below, grid lines are aligned with the tick marks:

However, if I specify the a grid interval as 1 day (the same value as the default), the grid lines start at the minimum X value as shown below and do not align with the tick marks

If the specified grid interval is equal to the spacing between x-axis tick marks, how can I make the major grid lines align with the tick marks? When the specified grid interval is an a  fraction 1/n of the time between tick marks, I'd also like every nth grid line to align with a tick mark.

Is this WinForms, WPF, Asp.Net or what?

WinForms using the .Net Chart control

I just encountered this issue, turns out that the best way to set the major grid lines manually is to use the Interval property of the Axis object, not MajorGrid.
So to get the major grid lines and the labels to line up, simply use:
Graph.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1.5

Using:
Graph.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 1.5

Will cause cause the behavior that you have encountered, where the grid lines and labels don't match up.  Apparently there's an offset you can apply to MajorGrid to make them line up, but for my application I didn't want anything fancy, so using AxisX.Interval worked the best.
You probably want to use MinorGrid for the lines between tick marks, but I haven't used that before myself.
